# Set row color in TLMDGrid

Tags: delphi, grid

I'm using **LMD Innovative** library in my inherited Delphi project, and in particular the **TLMDGrid** component.
I just want to set last row color (summary) different from the rest of the table.
I can set different colors for different columns in the designer, but (due to poor documentation) cannot find how to set color for a single row.
Thanks for help.

Comment: Can you post the public/published properties of the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use the LMD grids myself, so the following is based on their most recent trial download.

I wasn't sure whether you were asking about the `TLMDGrid` or the `TLMDDbGrid` so the
minimal demo below shows how to set the last row of both of them to a specific color.  As you'll
see, it is just a question of setting up an `OnGetCellColor` event handler for each grid, and then
setting the value of the `AColor` variable by whatever criteria suit you.

The `onGetCellColor` event is passed the current column as well as the
row number of the grid cell which is about to be drawn, so this show give 
you the possibility of coloring cells in the same row differently if you want.

I confess I'm not very happy with basing the test on the `OnGetCellColor` event of `LMDDBGrid1`
on the dataset's `RecordCount`, because not all dataset types return a meaningful value
(and for some, there can be  big performance hit in getting its value.  With a standard TDBGrid,
in its drawing events, you can rely on the dataset cursor being synced with the event calls (so that
any data values can be picked up from the current dataset row).  I'm not sure yet about how
you would do that with the LMD grid - obviously the best place to ask about that would be LMD themselves.

Code:

```
unit LMDGridTestu;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  DB, DBClient, Grids, LMDGrid, LMDDBGrid;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    CDS1: TClientDataSet;
    DataSource1: TDataSource;
    CDS1ID: TIntegerField;
    CDS1Name: TStringField;
    LMDDBGrid1: TLMDDBGrid;
    LMDGridIntegerColumn1: TLMDGridIntegerColumn;
    LMDGridTextColumn1: TLMDGridTextColumn;
    LMDGrid1: TLMDGrid;
    NameCol: TLMDGridTextColumn;
    IDCol: TLMDGridIntegerColumn;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure LMDDBGrid1GetCellColor(Sender: TObject; ACellState:
        TLMDGridCellStates; ARowState: TLMDGridRowState; const AData: Variant;
        AColumn: TLMDGridColumn; ARow: Integer; var AColor: TColor);
    procedure LMDGrid1GetCellColor(Sender: TObject; ACellState: TLMDGridCellStates;
        ARowState: TLMDGridRowState; const AData: Variant; AColumn: TLMDGridColumn;
        ARow: Integer; var AColor: TColor);
  public
  end;

[...]

procedure TForm1.LMDDBGrid1GetCellColor(Sender: TObject; ACellState:
    TLMDGridCellStates; ARowState: TLMDGridRowState; const AData: Variant;
    AColumn: TLMDGridColumn; ARow: Integer; var AColor: TColor);
begin
  if ARow = CDS1.Recordcount - 1 then
    AColor := clYellow;
end;

procedure TForm1.LMDGrid1GetCellColor(Sender: TObject; ACellState:
    TLMDGridCellStates; ARowState: TLMDGridRowState; const AData: Variant;
    AColumn: TLMDGridColumn; ARow: Integer; var AColor: TColor);
begin
  if ARow = LMDGrid1.DataRowCount - 1 then  //  Rows are numbered from zero
    AColor := clYellow;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  CDS1.CreateDataSet;
  CDS1.IndexFieldNames := 'ID';
  for i := 1 to 12 do
    CDS1.InsertRecord([i, StringOfChar(Chr((ord('a') + i -1)),  20)]);
  CDS1.First;

  LMDGrid1.DataRowCount := 10;

  for i := 0 to LMDGrid1.DataRowCount - 1 do begin
    LMDGrid1.Cells[IDCol.Position, i] := IntToStr(i);
    LMDGrid1.Cells[NameCol.Position, i] := 'Name' + IntToStr(i);
  end;

end;
```

Comment: Did this answer your q?

Comment: Sorry @Martyn I was busy, Tomorrow I will try your solution. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I used the GetCellColors (plural) event, since I had to set both foreground and background color. However it worked ! Thanks a lot !